# Trying to Find Article by Tukey

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, robust

I am trying to find a commonly cited paper by John Tukey published in 1960 called "A
survey of sampling from contaminated distributions", from a monograph(?) called "Contributions in Probability and Statistics".

I can not find this article from either a Google search or a database search from my home university's library.

I am wondering if anyone can provide information that would help me locate this article.

Answer (score 3):

Tukey, J. W. 1960. 
A survey of sampling from contaminated distributions. 
In Olkin, I., Ghurye, S.G., Hoeffding, W., Madow, W.G. and Mann, H.B. (Eds) 
*Contributions to Probability and Statistics: Essays in Honor of Harold Hotelling.* 
Stanford, CA: Stanford University Press, 448-485.

See also e.g. [this bibliography](http://www.netlib.org/bibnet/authors/t/tukey-john-w.html).

Comment: Thanks for the information, but my problem is that I actually have all this information (along with its ISBN, etc), yet I cannot find it in my library's database (and it searches that of other university libraries in its statewide system) nor on Google. I'd like to know if perhaps there is an online copy somewhere. But looking at the bibliography on Tukey, it may be in one of the sites devoted to his writings, so I'll give it a look. Thanks again

Comment: Matt, the chances of there being a legal online copy are slim. Try going to the library and enquiring about inter-library loans.

Comment: That wasn't clear to me; the details you give in your question aren't complete and the book title is slightly incorrect. I don't know an online version of the paper.

Comment: @Glen_b  I think you're right, in that the library is probably going to have to do some digging, but with the holidays that will be a few days. However, the bibliography of Nick's looks like it contains a lot of Tukey's work, it's worth a shot.

Comment: When I search google on the title in Nick's answer, the first link I get is exactly that reference in google books - it shows me all but a few pages of the main article and all but a few pages of the appendix. It also seems to omit one diagram and a page from the references. That would be a pretty good start until you can get the actual thing.

Comment: Somebody just upvoted this (thanks). Being reminded of the thread reminds  me to comment that **this paper wasn't included in any of the 8 volumes published of Tukey's _Collected Works._** Several  more volumes were planned, but the project stalled, or faded away, I gather for all too standard reasons: the money ran out.